# Datastore Design Inquiry

Tags: python, database-design, google-app-engine

I'm creating a Trivia app, and need some help designing my model relationships.  This question may get fairly complicated, but I'll try to be concise.

Trivia questions will all be part of a particular category.  Categories may be a category within another category.  If a trivia question is created/removed, I need to make sure that I also update a counter.  In this way, I'll be able to see how many questions are in each category, and display that back to users.  If a category has 'child' categories, I will need a way of displaying a cumulative counter of all sub-categories.  Accurate tallies are fairly important, but not mission critical.  I do not mind using sharded counters.  My question is, how should I design this so that it will adopt GAE denormalization, and maintain optimization?

I was thinking of having a Category class, with a ListProperty in each, which will represent the ancestor tree.  It will contain a key to each parent entity in the tree, in order.  But, should I also specify a parent when constructing the entities, or is that not needed in this case?  I'm thinking that I may have to run my counter updates in transaction, which is why I am considering a parent-child relationship.

Or perhaps there is more optimized way of designing my relationships that will still allow me to keep fairly accurate counters of all questions in each category.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: slightly off topic but I noticed you will be using app engine as the datastore.  Do you have some experience with app engine and creating persistent models? If not, I would point out that App Engine acts a little differently than many other persisten models.  I have found that there are several constraints that you are faced with when using App Engine as opposed to something more generic like Hibernate (in the Java world).  For example querying attribute pathss, e.g. you could not query triviaCard.someCategory.question. Just a heads up to work these constraints into your design if use GAE

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to your comment or not, but I am not using the Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't as complicated as you might think. Here's a Category class:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    subcategories = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
    quizzes = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    def add_sub_category(self, title):
        new_category = Category(title)
        new_category.put()
        self.subcategories.append(new_category)
        self.put()

        return new_category
```

By keeping both the subcategories and quizzes that are assocaited with this Category in a ListProperty, getting a count of them is as simple as using the len() operator.

You could use it something like this:

```
main_category = Category("Main")
main_category.put()

sports_category = main_category.add_sub_category("Sports")
baseball_category = sports_category.add_sub_category("Baseball")
football_category = sports_category.add_sub_category("Football")
hockey_category = sports_category.add_sub_category("Hockey")

tv_category = main_category.add_sub_category("TV")
```

...etc...

Comment: I just can't see this as a scalable option.  I could have somewhere in the thousands of quizzes, and that just doesn't seem like a logical amount of keys to store in a ListProperty.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: Each Category stores only the keys of the categories that it is the parent of.

Comment: I'm referring to your quizzes = db.ListProperty(db.Key).  That seems like a key for each list in that category, no?

Comment: Really? Thousands of quizzes per category?

Comment: There will be both quizzes, and standalone questions.  Even 100+ keys in a ListProperty seems prone to failure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Google App Engine, but here are some thoughts.  First is to consider if "tags" are more appropriate than category & sub categories.  Will their be a rigid 2 level category scheme?  Will all items have a main and subcategory assignment?

Rather than having a class for each category, have you considered a CategoryList class that would have a incrementCategoryByName(str name) method?  The class contain a dictionary of classes without having to have the overhead of a class for each category.

Comment: There will not be a rigid 2-level scheme.  There may be instances of something like:  Entertainment->TV->Seinfeld.

My worry about using tags is that certain tags may be applicable to more than one genre of trivia.  For example, Civil War may be a historical category, but it may also be the name of a movie (if one exists).

I'll consider the second part of your post, and respond again.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your post, I don't think that is feasible for the same reason that tagging is probably not feasible.  There may be circumstances where categories in different trees will share the same name.